# Possible to rename iOS App before uploading?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-distribution

I'm about to upload my app to AdHoc for Beta Testing however the Xcode project is named "MyApp" (not the actual name of the app) but I want to upload it to the app store as "MyLive". The bundle identifier is also com.myproject.MyApp but I would like to rename it if possible to something like com.mycompany.MyLive.

At the moment this is just a personal app attatched to my personal App ID but I'd like to future proof it as best as I can so it doesnt cause me any problems down the line.

As I've enrolled in the Apple Dev program using my personal Apple ID the only team I can choose is my name. However, is it possible to create a new team so that it seems like a company based around the app?

Lastly, if I upload it connected to my personal Apple ID how much personal information will be publicly visible? Is it possible to hide my email address?

EDIT: Is it possible to transfer an App from on Apple Developer account to another? Say when my current membership runs out and I set one up in the company name would I be able to transfer ownership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've created an app in iTunes Connect the bundle identifier can never be changed.  If you have created it as `com.myproject.MyApp` then it's stuck as such.  However, if this is your first upload, there's really no loss to create a different iTunes app with the bundle id of `com.mycompany.MyLive`.

None of that really matters though as no one will ever see this except you and anyone you've allowed on to your account.  Just keep it simple.

You can rename your iTunes app name when your app is in editable state.  i.e. If you've already submitted version 1.0 of the app with an iTunes app name of 'MyApp', you cannot change it for that version.  But you can setup a version 1.1 and change the name before it's submitted.

It's not possible to create new 'teams'.  A team is basically a developer account.  You can be invited to join other teams via the owner of those accounts.  In the future you can convert your personal account to a business account.  It requires a bit of legal paperwork but is not hard.

The only publicly available information is what you've added when creating your iTunes Connect app.  You have to add an email under review contact info, this is only used by Apple to reach you in case of questions with your app.  You are also required to provide a support URL so your customers can reach you.

Everything you wanted to know about what goes on iTunes:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html

Google's answer for ability to transfer apps:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Comment: Thanks @Frankie your answer was perfect in answering my questions. Appreciate the help.